# right way to embed/use mediaelement.js

Tags: html5-video, mediaelement.js, flash-video

I'm looking for the right way to embed the mediaelement.js player.

I have to add the player dynamically because I don't know the URL of the video at the beginning. The video will always be a MP4-video. How can I make sure that every browser uses the right player/plugin to be able to display the video? Current versions of Firefox for example can playback HTML5 video but it doesn't support MP4 - in this case the HTML5-video with flash fallback works but what about silverlight? I want to make sure that I'm doing this the right way (JS-only or jQuery-based doesn't matter).

Comment: I'm new to mediaelement too and currently looking at putting it into a corporate website. All of your questions can be answered by reading the documentation! http://mediaelementjs.com/

Comment: @KevinBrydon no, sadly not. I did read the docs but couldn't find the answer I was looking for. If you got the answer, please post it ...

Answer (score -1):

MediaElement (and all other html5 video wrappers) is designed to take all this worry away. If a clients browser supports html5 video but not `mp4` natively (as is the case with all browsers except IE9+ and Safari) then it will try to play the `mp4` using the flash player.

You may wish to encode your videos is other formats such as `ogv` or `webm` to enable other browsers to use their native html5 functionality.

The documentation can be found on the [mediaelement github](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement) site.

Comment: but as I said in my question - how do I have to setup the HTML and JavaScript for this to work as you described? And what about the silverlight plugin - how does this work?

Comment: There's practically no information on the front page of the site, no clear documentation and no good examples on how to do basic things.

Comment: @AariaCarter-Weir the page must have changed since posting the question. I've updated the link as it looks like the documentation is now mostly in the github repository. I should have probably added a code example when originally answering the question.